# Issue with symlink on Mac

Tags: macos, openssl

I recently istalled LibreSSL on my Mac and created a symlink as below:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/opt/libressl/bin/openssl /usr/local/bin/openssl
```

Although the link seems to have created correctly, when I type openssl version, it gives me the older version OpenSSL that was already there.

```
mbp-002127:docker abasu$ which openssl
/usr/local/bin/openssl
mbp-002127:docker abasu$ ls -lrt /usr/local/bin/openssl
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  35 Mar 10 17:44 /usr/local/bin/openssl -> /usr/local/opt/libressl/bin/openssl
mbp-002127:docker abasu$ /usr/local/bin/openssl version
LibreSSL 2.8.3
mbp-002127:docker abasu$ openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Maybe your PATH is not up to date? Have you try it in a new Terminal?

Comment: What does `type openssl` show? Also, what is your `$PATH`?